# using find command to search for all files having some text pattern

Tags: find, command

I use following find command to find and show all files having the input text pattern.

find . -type f -print|xargs grep -n "pattern"

I have many project folders each of which has its own makefile named as 'Makefile'.(no file extension, just 'Makefile')

How do i use above command to search for a certain pattern only in the files named Makefile which are present in all my project folders?

-AD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-print` is not required (at least by GNU `find` implementation). `-name` argument allows to specify filename pattern. Hence the command would be:

`find . -name Makefile | xargs grep pattern`

Answer (score 2):

If you have spaces or odd characters in your directory paths youll need to use the null-terminated method:

```
 find . -name Makefile -print0 | xargs -0 grep pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name 'Makefile' | xargs egrep -n "pattern"
```

use egrep if you have very long paths

Duplicate of : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637467/xargs-and-find)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the use of `xargs` by using `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -name 'Makefile' -exec egrep -Hn "pattern" {} \;
```

`-H` on `egrep` to output the full path to the matching files.

Answer (score 1):

grep -R "string" /path

Please find this link 
http://rulariteducation.blogspot.in/2016/03/how-to-check-particluar-string-in-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use ff command i.e ff -p .format. For eg ff -p *.txt

Answer (score 0):

Find big files occupying large disk space

we need to combine multiple command .

```
find . -type f | xargs du -sk | sort -n | tail;
```